# Gensim coefficients are nan and all the same

Tags: python, machine-learning, gensim, lda

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/)

The result I'm getting has `nan` for the coefficients. My data set has has two columns: tweets and ingestion dates. I have copied the code exactly and just made a few substitutions like tweet-prepreocessor. Any thoughts? Does the original file need the target and target names column like in the tutorial?

```
# Build LDA model
lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus,
                                           id2word=id2word,
                                           num_topics=20, 
                                           random_state=100,
                                           update_every=1,
                                           chunksize=100,
                                           passes=10,
                                           alpha='auto',
                                           per_word_topics=True)
# Print the Keyword in the 10 topics
pprint(lda_model.print_topics())
doc_lda = lda_model[corpus]

[(0,
  'nan*"fortnite" + nan*"louis" + nan*"yvr" + nan*"knowhttps" + '
  'nan*"problematic" + nan*"zellepay" + nan*"ritual" + nan*"underway" + '
  'nan*"mot" + nan*"tsb"'),
 (1,
  'nan*"fortnite" + nan*"louis" + nan*"yvr" + nan*"knowhttps" + '
  'nan*"problematic" + nan*"zellepay" + nan*"ritual" + nan*"underway" + '
  'nan*"mot" + nan*"tsb"'),
 (2,
  'nan*"fortnite" + nan*"louis" + nan*"yvr" + nan*"knowhttps" + '
  'nan*"problematic" + nan*"zellepay" + nan*"ritual" + nan*"underway" + '
  'nan*"mot" + nan*"tsb"'),
 (3,
  'nan*"fortnite" + nan*"louis" + nan*"yvr" + nan*"knowhttps" + '
  'nan*"problematic" + nan*"zellepay" + nan*"ritual" + nan*"underway" + '
  'nan*"mot" + nan*"tsb"'),
 (4,...
```

Answer (score 1):

Not allowed to comment on your issue but I'm getting the same error from the same tutorial. I haven't seen any solutions for it and I'm not sure what the issue could be. The phraser and preprocessing are all the same and for some reason no one else is getting this error. I don't think it has anything to do with target_names though, because at one point she turns the content values into a list (I did it similarly: `df.content.values.tolist())` and deals exclusively with that

**Update: if you're having this issue, upgrade your version of numpy (it's a numpy issue). For me, conda install numpy="1.14.5" worked.**

Comment: I definitely think it has to do with our numpy versions being wrong; someone else was able to run it perfectly fine on their computer, so I think gensim probably just has a dependency on an older version of numpy

Answer (score -1):

I solve it by upgrading numpy to 1.15.0 version.